# GeoFact(s) - Enigmatic Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, geography, science, symbols

[image: GeoFact(s)]

Clues:
(Ge) is to (S) as (Sr) is to (__)!, 12.#40.

Instructions:
Put these symbols in the correct order and orientation (contextual images)

Comment: Do the 2 underscores indicate the answer to the analogy is 2 letters?

Comment: I considered a multiplicative relationship rather than an additive one, but the analogue would be 19 (Potassium), which doesn't have a two-letter abbreviation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution Part 1:

> A common way to show equalities between quantities is to set them up in to fractions. Remember the phrase "***cross multiply and divide***"? 
>  Setting this up as two equal fractions, we change "Ge is to S as Sr is to [blank] like ***Ge/S=Sr/x*** where x is a variable.

Solution Part 2:

> Ge is the chemical symbol for Germanium (Atomic number ***32***). S is Sulfer (***16***). Sr is Stronium (***38***). The resulting equation when substituting atomic numbers becomes 32/16=38/x. Solving for x, we get x=***19*** (Sodium).

Solution Part 3:

> The exclamation point at the blank for 19 shows that we must take the ***factorial*** of the number, which equals ***121,645,100,408,832,000***.

Solution Part 4:

> The next few characters in the clue read "***12.#40***". These correspond with digits in the factorial number from Solution 3. The number 12 starts the factorial number, and the number 40 is right in the middle. This leads us to the ***GPS coordinates*** of ***12.1645100, 40.8832000***.

Solution Part 5:

> The GPS coordinates bring us to Sehana Museli, Ethiopia. By inserting that in to google again, we get the Etheopian spelling of Sehana Museli, **ሰአና ሙሌ** 
>  [image]

Comment: Ok then what is the relation of this to those symbols? Also, if you present the answer, why the bounty?

Comment: For fun, of course!

Comment: While it is, of course, your prerogative to self-answer a puzzle you feel hasn't gotten a satisfactory answer, it is generally nicer to give a solver some hints and some time to let them come up with the full solution themselves, and/or to annotate their final solution with (e.g.) "Added by OP" notes that fill in missing or incorrect details. 
See also [How long should I wait before providing the answer to my riddle?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2799) and its answers, which suggest other avenues than self-answering (which one answer describes as a last resort).

Answer (score 3):

Combining both Deusovi's and Tyler's answers, the final answer must be:

> ሰኣና ሙሌ

Which is the name of

> the region pinpointed by Tyler (Sehana Museli, Ethiopia), using the characters from the Ge'ez script discovered by Deusovi.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully understand the "clue" but:

> These are letters in the Geʽez (or Ethiopic) script. In alphabetical order, they are:
>
>  ሌ (le); ሙ (mu) ሰ (sä); ና (na); አ (ʾä)

If this is the correct answer (and there's no additional reordering that I'm missing), it's possible that

> "Ge + S" is meant to hint at Geʽez, because it sounds the same. The 'obvious'-seeming alternative is that the analogy uses the periodic table, which would have answer `Ti` for Titanium - I'm not sure what the exclamation point or "#40" could mean, though, and there's no clear connection to the Geʽez script.